# How to convert a C++ STL vector iterator to a vector reverse iterator?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, iterator, insertion-sort

I have used a nested `for`-loop to carry out insertion sort on a C++ STL `<vector>`. The first `for`-loop is over an iterator and the second one, over a reverse_itr.

I need to pass the index (iterator pointer value) from the first loop to the second. I have tried the following approach but it gives me this error

```
error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are 
‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’ and 
‘std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator’ {aka 
‘std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >’})
```

```
void insertionSort(int size, vector<int> arr) {

    for(auto itr = arr.begin(); itr != arr.end() - 1; ++itr) {

        int element = *(itr + 1);
        cout << "Element being compared with preceding sub-array is : " << element << endl;

        for(auto r_itr = (itr + 1); r_itr != arr.rend(); ++r_itr) {

            if(*(r_itr+1) <= element) {
                *r_itr = element;
                break;
            }
            else {
                *r_itr = *(r_itr+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I searched up quite a lot online, found a way to convert a reverse iterator to an iterator (using `itr.base()`) but not the other way round.

Also I am new to C++ STL and algorithms, please feel free to suggest any way to improve my code with respect to the "clean"-ness of code or the algorithm itself!

Comment: You *will* dereference the `end` iterators with your code (in `*(itr + 1)` and `*(r_itr+1)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to `for(vector<int>::reverse_iterator r_itr(next(itr)); r_itr != arr.rend(); ++r_itr)`

To expand on their working, `reverse_iterator` is not implemented the same as `iterator`. The logical and physical address for an `iterator` are the same but for `reverse_iterator`, the logical and physical address are not the same. For example: `s.end()` and `s.rbegin()` have the same physical address but `*s.end()` will give you an error but `*s.rbegin()` will give you the last value of the container `s`.

The code below will make things clear:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<int> S{ 1, 2, 3 };
    
    set<int>::iterator itr = S.find(2);
    cout << *itr << endl;

    set<int>::reverse_iterator r_itr(itr);
    cout << *r_itr << endl;

    cout << itr._Ptr << ' ' << r_itr.base()._Ptr << endl;

    //S.erase(r_itr);       // ERROR!
    S.erase(r_itr.base());

    for (int e : S)
        cout << e << ' ';
}
```

On my machine, it produced the following output:

> ```
> 2
> 1
> 00F85DA8 00F85DA8
> 1 3
> ```

Comment: and access the element simply by `*r_itr`. This will give you the element before `*itr` for the very first time.

Comment: Yes, I realised that it was unnecessary to use a variable for getting the element. My smol brain LOL.

Comment: Damn, you keep editing your answer and I had to read again and again 
Henceforth, I'll read answers an hour later, haha!
Thanks for your kind answer though, worked like a charm!

Comment: I have seen many code examples where they use the scope resolution operator `::` instead of directly using the class or function. Why is it done like that? Also why use  set<int>::iterator itr = S.find(2), when u could simply say auto itr = S.find(2) ?

Comment: @louis.shawn I did it that way to be clear. But in your for loop, you need to use the scope rosolution method as auto r_itr(itr) could also mean you're just copying `itr` which is an `iterator` into `r_itr` which could be both `iterator` or `reverse_iterator`. Hope you understand, not good English.

Answer (score 2):

The class template `std::vector` has random access iterators. So there is no any need to convert a given "forward" iterator to a "reverse" iterator.

Just use with iterators the `operator --` instead of the `operator ++` or vice versa where it is required.

Pay attention to that the parameter `size` is not used in your function declared like

```
void insertionSort(int size, vector<int> arr);
```

If you want to sort a range from a vector then use two parameters declared as iterators that specify a range.

For example

```
void insertionSort( std::vector<int>::iterator first, std::vector<int>::iterator last );
```

Or you can write a more general function for vectors of any types using templates.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void insertionSort( std::vector<int>::iterator first, std::vector<int>::iterator last )
{
    if ( first != last )
    {
        for ( auto current = first; ++current != last; )
        {
            typename std::iterator_traits<decltype( current )>::value_type
                value( *current );

            auto prev = current, next = current;

            while ( next != first && value < *--prev )
            {
                *next-- = *prev;
            }

            if ( next != current ) *next = value;
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    const int N = 10;
    
    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );
    
    std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( v ), N, [=]{ return std::rand() % N; } );
    
    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    insertionSort( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ) );
    
    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
0 6 6 7 4 3 4 6 6 1 
0 1 3 4 4 6 6 6 6 7
```

Comment: I was so caught up excited about the `iterator` and `reverse iterator` (I just started coding in C++, I mostly use C or Python), that I forgot about the fundamental logic of using the `--itr`. I am overwhelmed!